# TypeScript Multiple DropDown Submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a dropdown that multi selects data when I want to submit data single dropdown values submits and multiple dropdown data goes null any solution?

```
//Drop Down Data
const permission = [
  {permissionIds:1,permit:'Oliver Hansen'},
  {permissionIds:2,permit:'Van Henry'},
  {permissionIds:3,permit:'April Tucker'}
];

export default function RoleNewEditForm() {

  const [permit, setPermit] = useState<string[]>([])
  const handleChange=(event: SelectChangeEvent<string[]>)=>{
    const{
      target:{value}
    }=event;
    setPermit(
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(','):value
    )
  }

//Role Interface
export interface IRole {
  id?:number;
  applicationId: number | undefined;
  name: string | null;
  description: string | null;
  permissionIds:string |null;
}
  const {
    reset,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isSubmitting },
  } = methods;


//Submit Data here
  const onSubmit = (data: IRole) => {
    console.log(data);

  };


  return (
    <>
      <FormProvider methods={methods} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     
                
                  <RHFTextField name="description" label="Description" />
                <FormControl>
                  <InputLabel>Permission</InputLabel>
                  <Select multiple 
                          value={permit} onChange={handleChange}  name="permissionIds" label="Permissions"
                          renderValue={(value: Array<string>) => value.length ? value.join(','): <></>}>
                    {permission.map((per=>{
                      return <MenuItem key={per.permissionIds} value={per.permissionIds}>{per.permit}</MenuItem>
                    }))}
                 
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have added interface and submit function also with the form value
So now it could be clear to detect my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify more exactly what the issue is? What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: @DrewReese
I have Form With Multi Select DropDowon that is in Above Code When i when i Select Multiple Item and Submit That than The item of Drop down Submits Null from form

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? It seems the issue you describe is related to submitting the form? See [mcve]. What is null? What is being submitted?

Comment: @DrewReese Now It may Clear i have Attach all from abn with interface and so Please Kindly Check it's a big problem iam facing about 3 days

Comment: So are you saying that `data`, or some part of it, passed to `onSubmit` is undefined? Where is `methods` declared? What is the `FormProvider` component doing with these props? Where is the form state declared that you are submitting?

Comment: <Select multiple 
                          value={permit} onChange={handleChange}  name="permissionIds" label="Permissions"
                          renderValue={(value: Array<string>) => value.length ? value.join(','): <></>}>
                    {permission.map((per=>{
                      return <MenuItem key={per.permissionIds} value={per.permissionIds}>{per.permit}</MenuItem>
                    }))}
                 
                  </Select>
@DrewReese
everything is ok only this Dropdwon submit Null Value and i can't post all code because stackOverlow dont let to post alot

Comment: Well, what isn't overtly clear to me is how this input is connected to any form submission. Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Sir This is Code Sand Box the Problem when i submit form dropdown item submits nulls https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-saha-qh5tip?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `permissionIds` form state is `null` because this is what it is initialied to:

```
const defaultValues = useMemo<IRole>(
  () => ({
    id: 0,
    name: null,
    applicationId: 0,
    description: null,
    permissionIds: null // <-- initialized null
  }),
  []
);

const methods = useForm<IRole>({
  resolver: yupResolver(NewRoleSchema),
  defaultValues // <-- initial form values
});
```

And this part of form state is never updated since it's not controlled.

## Solution

Wrap the multi-select component in the `Controller` component from `react-hook-form` and pass the appropriate props. Provide valid initial state.

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
```

...

```
interface IRole {
  id?: number;
  applicationId: number | undefined;
  name: string; // <-- string type
  description: string; // <-- string type
  permissionIds: string[]; // <-- string array type
}
```

...

```
const defaultValues = useMemo<IRole>(
  () => ({
    id: 0,
    name: "", // <-- string
    applicationId: 0,
    description: "", // <-- string
    permissionIds: [] // <-- empty array
  }),
  []
);

...

<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>Permission</InputLabel>
  <Controller
    name="permissionIds"
    control={control}
    render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
      <Select
        {...field}
        multiple
        label="Permissions"
        renderValue={(value: Array<string>) => value.join(",")}
      >
        {permission.map((per) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem
              key={per.permissionIds}
              value={per.permissionIds}
            >
              {per.permit}
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
    )}
  />
</FormControl>
```

[image: Edit typescript-multiple-dropdown-submit]

[image]